# Elasticsearch 5.1 Java API Highlighting

Tags: java, elasticsearch

Could you please provide an example of how to highlight queries in all fields using Elasticsearch 5.1 Java API?

```
    HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder = new HighlightBuilder()
            .postTags("<highlight>")
            .preTags("</highlight>")
            .highlightQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery( "ferrari"));


    SearchRequestBuilder request = client.prepareSearch("notemates")
            .setTypes("cars")
            .setQuery(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery( "ferrari"))
            .setSearchType(SearchType.DEFAULT)
            .highlighter(highlightBuilder);
    SearchResponse response = request.get();
```

Is something wrong?

Many thanks.

Comment: *is* something wrong? Are you getting an error or not seeing the highlights or what?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I don't receive highlights, there is now error.

Comment: could you show your mappings? and at least 1 sample document?

Comment: for example for localhost:9200/notemates/cars/1 I have an object {"title":"ferrari FF"}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specifically add the fields you are using to the HighlightBuilder:

```
HighlightBuilder highlightBuilder = new HighlightBuilder()
        .postTags("<highlight>")
        .preTags("</highlight>")
        .field("title");
```